# My destination field is the same name but with a prefix, how to map automatically

Tags: automapper

The DTO object has nearly the identical field name however without prefix 'db_' in it, e.g. my database entity field 'db_firstname' my dto name 'firstname', how do I tell automapper to automaticaly map it, instead I manually write 200 lines.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need RecognizePrefixes. The docs are [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#recognizing-prepostfixes).